# Roles, Groups or What?

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups

We use Drupal as the basis for a student information website. We have 3 intakes of students a year and I would like to be able to allocate students various rights based on roles, primarily if they are

- a current student,
- an applying student,
- or an alumni.

But I would also like to be able to identify them by what class they did.

- Should I create a new role for each new intake?
- Should I use groups?
- Is there an alternative method I should use?

Comment: It also depends on what rights you would like to allocate them. But basically, I think you could examine rights if a student has a role AND another, then he/she has the right to do something - e.g. IF he is a current student AND goes to the second class, THEN he/she can participate in.... etc.

Comment: But these don't necessarily have to be roles: the beginning and the end of the studies are known data. From these data, other conditions can also be calculated. OR these roles could even be updated periodically (yearly).

Comment: @Sk8erPeter I'm afraid your not making much sense, and could you please delete your comments and make them an answer?

Comment: `I'm afraid your not making much sense` - really BIG thanks for saying this after I'm trying to help you... :D I referred to writing a simple module to restrict access depending on roles as a user can have multiple roles (e.g. "currently student" role AND "goes to second class" role, etc.) - or depending on the beginning year of the studies, you can calculate if someone is still a student or not, etc. BUT if you don't understand what someone is trying to say, you could ASK instead of insulting him/her with saying his words don't make any sense at all, especially when he/she tries to help you.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter you should post your comments as an answer and let others decide if you are making sense.

Comment: One thing is proven: you don't deserve any help if you speak like that. If you had a little empathy (or intelligence?) you could have said: "OK, thanks for your comment, but it doesn't help me out", and that would be the end of it. If you have text interpretation problems, this doesn't mean that the one that tries to HELP YOU (do you understand the meaning of it yet?) is stupid. Shame on you. I just tried to START a discussion about the possibilities, I didn't try to give you the one and only solution.

Comment: StackExchange is a place for getting answers to questions, not for discussions, your ramblings are neither helpful or useful. Also as I said before they should be an answer.  if you had posted it as an answer you would have given people the chance to vote it down for not being helpful.  both Chapabu and Nikhil provided me with considered answers to my questions, as answers not as comments. I thanked them by voting up their answers.  The FAQ explains this. I merely said that your comments did not make sense, which I'm afraid they did not, I wasn't trying to cause offence.

Comment: Pls don't tell me what's Drupal Answers about...Some kind of reactions for comments can later produce a good answer, but maybe you haven't seen such questions where this happened yet...which doesn't mean commenting is useless. That wasn't a complete answer, which explains why I didn't post it as an answer. You just howled down what I said instead of intelligently asking what I referred to. Once again: I primarily referred to storing the beginning year of the studies from which you can calculate if someone is a current student or not, to which class he goes to - and restrict access based on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best and simple way is to assigning Roles.

[Users, roles and permissions](http://drupal.org/node/120614)

Comment: Is the roles system designed to have 10's or 100's of Roles?

Comment: Yes. But there will be some design mess of course.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably initially set up the Current Student, Applying Student, and Alumni roles and get that out of the way.

I'd then have a content type called Class, and hold all of the class information you require in here.  I'd then use the [Entity Reference](http://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to create a link between each student, and any classes they take.  This will allow you to filter quite easily in Views and such users based on classes.

Alternatively, if the classes are required to have communities (i.e. people from the Biology class have a place to post information etc) I suppose you could use [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) and sign each student up to the relevent classes/groups.

If you need me to expand on anything or if this doesn't fit then please let me know in the comments and I'll see if I can help any more!

Answer (score 1):

You could, for sure, use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module for this. [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. It is designed to be an alternative to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

Some more details about the various **roles** used by the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module:

- *Configured Global Roles*: These roles can be configured via the admin interface of the Group module, they are available (to grant permissions) for all individual groups (regardless of the "Group Type"). These roles cannot have permissions that vary per group type (they are all the same). Typical examples of such roles could be "**Group Moderator**" or "**Group Administrator**".
- *Special Global Roles*: These are the special (hardcoded) roles named "**Outsider**" (= a signed in user that did not join a group) and "**Member**"  (= a signed in user that did join a group). These cannot be defined by the Drupal administrator, and they are always available for any group. Unlike Configured Global Roles, these roles can have different permissions sets for each group type. Special case: the role "**Anonymous**" is related to a user that is not signed).
- *Group Specific Roles*: These roles can be configured per group type and will only be available on groups of that group type. As an example, for a group type like "Class", you could configure roles such as "**Teacher**", "**Student**", "**Alumni**", etc.

## Integration with various modules

The Group module integrates with various other (popular) modules, including:

- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603136), as illustrated in the answer to the question "[How to bulk assign existing content to a group created with the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197489/)".
- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2540994), as illustrated in the answer to the question "[How to show the content of a group on the group page when using the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197552/)".
- [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/node/2343509).

The beauty, IMO, of these integrations are that they are more or less out-of-the box (not dozens of extra modules needed to make those integrations work).

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".