# How to publish in an organization with hierarchy?

Tags: nodes, workflows

My Drupal experience is limited to a single site with custom content types and standard roles. Please take a look at the use case below, involving content being routed through multiple organizational levels, so there is consolidation at each level and some content being "highlighted" for the next higher level.

My company has weekly activity reports. Each member submits an activity report and then the team lead chooses a few to be submitted to our section manager. Then our section manager chooses a few (from multiple teams) to be submitted to our division manager. Then our division chooses a few (from multiple sections) to be submitted to our top level manager.

What stuff should I look into to accomplish content going through different levels like this?

Comment: study orgnic groups

Comment: I forgot to mention Drupal 8, I don't see a groups module for 8.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/og/releases/8.x-1.x-dev, i have not tested yet.

Comment: Talking about a "GroupS" module for D8 ... How about the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module? Refer to my answer for more details ...

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module (commonly perceived as an alternative for [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og)).

[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable. Which also makes it integrate very well (out of the box) with commonly used modules such as [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules), [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views), etc.

Some more questions you may want to look at for more details:

- [What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493), which explains the various types of roles that can be used.
- [How to bulk assign existing content to a group created with the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197489), a typical issue when adding this module to an existing site.
- [What are the features of the Group module versus Organic Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197618)

## Sample configuration

Below is an example of a possible configuration, which may help to get you started with possible configurations (using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module):

```
Group type ID ! Group type ! Group role ID ! Role
--------------+------------+---------------+------------
 1            ! Class      ! 3             ! Instructor
 1            ! Class      ! 4             ! Student
 2            ! Customers  ! 5             ! Lead
 2            ! Customers  ! 6             ! Prospect
 2            ! Customers  ! 7             ! Licensed Customer
 2            ! Customers  ! 8             ! Sales
 2            ! Customers  ! 9             ! Support
 2            ! Customers  ! 10            ! Accounting
 2            ! Customers  ! 11            ! R&D
 3            ! Project    ! 12            ! Project Manager
 3            ! Project    ! 13            ! Developer
 3            ! Project    ! 14            ! Customer
```

#### Group Types

The above example consists of 3 ***group types***:

- Class.
- Customers.
- Project.

#### Group Roles

For each of the 3 group types, there are specific ***Roles*** defined, some more details about some of them:

- for the *Class* group, these are the 2 roles that are configured:

  - Instructor.
  - Student.
- for the *Project* group, these are the 3 roles that are configured:

  - Project Manager.
  - Developer.
  - Customer.

These are the *Group Specific Roles*: these roles can be configured per group type and will only be available on groups of that group type. As an example, for group type "*Class*", the defined roles are **Instructor** and **Student** (which are not available for the other group types.

On top of the group specific roles, there are also *Special Global Roles*: These are the special (hardcoded) roles named **Outsider** (= a signed in user that did not join a group) and **Member**  (= a signed in user that did join a group). These cannot be defined by the Drupal administrator, and they are always available for any group. These roles can have different permissions sets for each group type. Special case: the role **Anonymous** is related to a user that is not signed.

#### Groups

Each of the configured group types can have any number of ***Groups***.

Examples of groups:

- for the *Class* group type, there could be these **Groups**:

  - Getting started with Drupal.
  - Drupal for site builders.
  - Become an expert in using the Rules module.
- for the *Customers* group type, there could be these **Groups**:

  - Service Requests.
  - Order Processing.
  - Sales Orders.
  - Relationship Management.

#### Permissions

For each of the configured group types, you can then also configure for each ***Content Type*** which ***Role*** has what kind of access (= none, view, create, edit, delete). Be aware: even though this looks similar to Drupal's permission configuration, these permissions are not the same permissions (they are specific to the Group module).

## Your usecase

In your case, your challenge seems to be about this:

> ... content going through different levels like this?

Translated to an implementation using the Group module, it seems to me that all that's needed is to assign, and later on re-assign, each node (content) to an appropriate group. Whereas you use appropriate group permissions/roles to accutally perform these assignments.

And for the required group types to be configured, I'd start with these specific group types:

- Teams (with groups Team T1, Team T2, ..., Team Tn).
- Sections (with groups Section Sa, Section Sb, ..., Section Sx).
- Devisions (with groups DevX, DevY, DevZ).

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".