# How to create access permissions system similar to Organic Groups access, using Eck entities

Tags: 7, users, organic-groups, entities

There currently still is not a working version for [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) access control, compatible with [ECK entities](https://www.drupal.org/project/eck).

My current site contains entity type project and entity type project content.
The project content references the project through an [entityreference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field.

I would like to use an access control system that grants access to specific projects, and when that access is granted, the user has also access to specific project content entity types.

I know that Organic groups uses a relationship approach in which the group membership is an entity, and there is a two level deep relationship between group content (or group member) and the group.

In my case I prefer the simple direct entityreference (one level relation) between content and project. This would serve simplicity and performance. If you would advise against that, please let me kow.

I would like to receive guidance on how to set up such permission system, and possibly your suggestions and recomendations based on your experience with a similar setup. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd be willing to use the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, then you could do like so:

- You can configure a Group Type named "Project", so that this Group Type would replace your ***entity type project***.
- You can create 1 Group (of group type "Project") for each of your Projects (each Group probably labelled with the name of a specific project).
- You can assign nodes to a Group (of group type "Project"), so that these nodes would replace your ***project content entity types***.

[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. It is designed to be an alternative to [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og). The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

With the above in place, you also have the permission system you're looking for, out-of-the-Group-box.

#### More info:

- Refer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/197493/39516)" for more details about the supported roles.
- Refer to my answer to "[How to configure access to courses for teachers and students?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/150808/39516)" for a sample configuration.

#### Integration with various modules

The Group module integrates with various other (popular) modules, including:

- [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2603136), as illustrated in the answer to the question "[How to bulk assign existing content to a group created with the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197489/)".
- [Views](https://www.drupal.org/node/2540994), as illustrated in the answer to the question "[How to show the content of a group on the group page when using the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197552/)".
- [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/node/2343509).

The beauty, IMO, of these integrations are that they are more or less out-of-the box (not dozens of extra modules needed to make those integrations work).

#### Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".

Comment: Although I need it for a site that already has its entity structure and entityreferences in place for a a lot of content, I'll give Group a try and see how it works. Thank you and I'll report soon.

Comment: I got a fatal error right after enabling Group and Group Node on my existing site. https://www.drupal.org/node/2917347

Comment: Do you know if the Group Node submodule can be used for ECK entities, or is it restricted to nodes? I stopped using nodes two years ago.

Comment: I see hat the Group guys stopped working at the D7 version more than 2 years ago no commits since then. They only focus at D8 apparently.

Comment: @Yuri I never experienced an error like you reported in that D.O issue now (no idea what may cause it, sorry). To use the Group module with other (custom) entities: I've never done so myself, but maybe [this D7 docu issue](https://www.drupal.org/node/2845093) may help a little bit. "Stopped working" (for D7) is not really the right phrasing I think. It's rather something like "the D7 version seems functionally stabilized, though D7 related support issues still get addressed". Know however that there have been huge improvements in the D8 version of Group.